# How to get the request context in a freemaker template in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

How to get the request context path in `freemarker` template when using with `spring`?

My view resolver is like this

```
    <bean id="freeMarkerViewResolver" class="learn.common.web.view.FreemarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

My view resolver `learn.common.web.view.FreemarkerViewResolver` extends `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your view resolver you can add the following property

```
<property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
```

Then in your freemarker template you can get the request context patch like

```
${rc.getContextPath()}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ${rc.contextPath} to save a few more characters (in Spring 3, at least).

Comment: What is the type of the `rc` parameter?

Comment: @EliuX it's of type `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext` - so if you want to use it in a Freemarker Template, a `ftlvariable` directive like `<#-- @ftlvariable name="rc" type="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext" -->
` helps your IDE regarding code completion.

Answer (score 9):

If your requirement is to fetch the Context Path in your FTL view then Spring provides a better alternate -
First import spring.ftl in your view

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />
```

Then use macro @spring.url for the URL which you want to make context aware -

```
<li id="history"><a href="<@spring.url '/rest/server/taskHistory'/>">History</a></li>
```

This is very much similar to -

```
<li id="history"><a href="${rc.getContextPath()}/rest/server/taskHistory">History</a></li>
```

Where rc is defined in viewResolver

XML based configuration

```
<property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
```

or Spring Boot style configuration (aplication.yml)

```
spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute: rc
```

Comment: Or, if you use Spring Boot, you can use `springMacroRequestContext` variable: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${springMacroRequestContext.contextPath}/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`. Or set `spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute=rc` in app properties and then use `${rc.contextPath}` in any template.