# Get locale in freemarker template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

How can I get the current locale used in a freemarker template? I have seen implementation of `<spring.message code />`

I need this to do a conditional

```
<#if locale = DE >
.....
<#else>
....
</#if>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by the [Freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html):

> Special variables are variables defined by the FreeMarker engine itself. To access them, you use the .variable_name syntax
>
> .locale: Returns the current value of the locale setting. This is a string, for example en_US. For more information about locale strings see the setting directive.

So to access the current local within a Freemarker template you would use

```
The current locale is: ${.locale}
```

To use it in a conditional statement as per your requirements, you would do:

```
<#if .locale == "DE">
   ...
<#else>
   ...
</#if>
```

Comment: In practical use, you probably want `<#if .local?starts_with("de")>` to ignore the country code portion of the locale.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob Blake's answer is technically correct, but still I'd like to add some thoughts...

**1. Other locale-related variables**
There's not just `.locale`, but also `.lang` and since FreeMarker 2.3.21 also `.locale_object`, which provides the actual `java.lang.Locale` object (not just Strings).

See [Freemarker Special Variable Reference](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_specvar.html) for more information.

**2. Difference between request's locale and locale in RequestContext**
In some cases, the `Locale` provided by Freemarker is not the same as the `Locale` that you use.

In my case, I have a Freemarker Spring Boot Application with a `LocaleChangeInterceptor`, which allows you to set your own locale (e.g. in the session), so that the user can switch language when you use `<@spring.message />` to render the texts in different languages.

This code snippet is inspired by this [baeldung.com Spring Boot I18N tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization):

```
@Configuration
public class McvConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new SessionLocaleResolver();         
  }

  @Bean
  public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
  }

}
```

In this case after the Locale has been changed, the locale provided by Freemarker (i.e. `${.locale}`, `${.lang}` and `${.locale_object}`) and the Locale in the `RequestContext` (i.e. the Locale that is used for `<@spring.message />` for example) **differ**!

In this case, you should read the Locale from the `RequestContext` instead.

**Configuration class**

```
  @Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    final UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver(); // or TilesViewResolver or whatever
    // make requestContext available for Freemarker templates as "${rc}"
    viewResolver.setRequestContextAttribute("rc");
    return viewResolver;
  }
```

See also [SO - How to get the request context in a freemaker template in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249205/how-to-get-the-request-context-in-a-freemaker-template-in-spring)

**Freemarker template**

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="rc" type="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="${rc.locale.language!"en"}">
<!-- ... -->
</html>
```

So when you hit `http://<serverName>:<serverPort>/<contextPath>/index?lang=en` or `http://<serverName>:<serverPort>/<contextPath>/index?lang=de` or `http://<serverName>:<serverPort>/<contextPath>/index?lang=fr`, or whatever languages you application supports, the `<html>` tag's `lang` attribute will match the language from the `<@spring.message/>` localized texts.

Comment: Is it also possible to obtain the setting `time_zone` like `.time_zone_object`?

Comment: Yes, `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext` has a method `getTimeZone()`, so in this scenario, `${rc.timeZone}` gives access to this in Freemarker.