# Spring access to static resources

Tags: css, spring-mvc

I am having issue with loading static files in spring mvc. I have in my java config something like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

When I deploy my app and visit it in browser

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/
```

No CSS is loaded. When I go to source I see that path is something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/css/style.css
```

Which is incorrect. If I change it to:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/resources/css/style.css
```

Then I can see my css file. What am I doing wrong?
In my css I am linking to resources like this:

```
<link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you try resources/css/style.css in the link tag for the css?

Comment: Zeus's solution will not work for some URLs (e.g., `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/some/other/path.html`) as Sotirios explained in his answer, unless you specify proper <base> tag in your <head>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying a path like

```
<link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

where the path is prefixed with `/`, the browser appends that path to the your host, not to your application context. For example, say you made your first request to

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/
```

then your browser would try to get the css at

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/css/style.css
```

as you've noticed. If you don't put a `/` at the front of the path like

```
<link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

then the browser will use the current location URL as the base.

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/resources/css/style.css
```

But if the current URL was

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/some/other/path
```

then the same path css `<link>` would be resolved to

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/some/other/path/resources/css/style.css
```

which is not what you want.

You want to css link to always be resolved on your application's context path. You can do this with the JSTL `core` taglib like so

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

or with EL as

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

Comment: @artur See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249205/how-to-get-the-request-context-in-a-freemaker-template-in-spring

Comment: @Artur, this solution does not help to generate URLs in static JavaScript files. Though, using `<c:url>` has its own advantages.

Comment: I think You might me right but in Freemarker I can't use c:url.

Answer (score 0):

A leading slash in a URL makes it relative to the Host, in your case `http://localhost:8080/`. So to be relative to the current URL leave it out.

You can also use `<c:url >` which makes the address relative to the servlet address, no matter what the current URL is.

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
```

This way, even if you have opened the page `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/whatever/`, the stylesheet will have the correct URL.